# Add event from gmail to google calendar

Tags: events, calendar, gmail, addition

I want to automatically create an calendar event from gmail. 
I order to test the same I am using the URL (https://script.google.com) to test the same but the code is not working. 
The code is as follows:

File name - Code.js

```
function testSchemas() {
  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mail_template').getContent();
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
    subject: 'Test Email - ' + new Date(),
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
  });
}
```

File name - mail_template.html

```
<html>
 <body>
   <script type="application/ld+json">
   {
     "@context":              "http://schema.org",
     "@type":                 "EventReservation",
     "reservationNumber":     "IO12345",
     "underName": {
       "@type":               "Person",
       "name":                "Rahul Kumar"
     },
     "reservationFor": {
       "@type":               "Event",
       "name":                "Google I/O 2013",
       "startDate":           "2017-01-05T08:30:00-08:00",
       "location": {
         "@type":             "Place",
         "name":              "Moscone Center",
         "address": {
           "@type":           "PostalAddress",
           "streetAddress":   "800 Howard St.",
           "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
           "addressRegion":   "CA",
           "postalCode":      "94103",
           "addressCountry":  "US"
         }
       }
     }
   }
   </script>
   <p>
     Dear Rahul, thanks for booking your Google I/O ticket with us.
   </p>
   <p>
     BOOKING DETAILS<br/>
     Reservation number: IO12345<br/>
     Order for: Rahul Kumar<br/>
     Event: Google I/O 2013<br/>
     Start time: Jan 5th 2017 8:00am PST<br/>
     Venue: Moscone Center, 800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103<br/>
   </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is the code not working? Does it throw an exception or do something unexpected?

Comment: I does not throw any exception. Please suggest how to debug it.